# Undelete accidentally deleted records in Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

As title, possible? I have by accident deleted another record due to my ugly html interface in FireFox. The bad thing is this record delete is a root folder which the program automatically cascade delete everything :(

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [undark](http://www.pldaniels.com/undark/). I already used it. It it can export the rows (deleted or not) from a SQLite db file if the records were not overwritten. Last version [here](https://github.com/witwall/undark).

The [SQLite-Deleted-Records-Parser](https://github.com/mdegrazia/SQLite-Deleted-Records-Parser) does not give the same type of output, but can be useful.

And there are also some products like the [SQLite Forensic Explorer](http://www.sqliteviewer.org/), [SQLite Repair](https://www.stellarinfo.com/sqlite-repair.php), [Sqlite Database Recovery](https://www.systoolsgroup.com/sqlite-database-recovery.html) and [SQLiteDoctor](http://www.sqlabs.com/sqlitedoctor.php).

If you are a developer you can avoid having the same problem again using [litereplica](http://litereplica.io). It adds single-master replication to SQLite.

But remember to enable the point-in-time recovery because as the transactions are replicated to the replicas an accidental command like `DROP TABLE` or `DELETE FROM` will also be replicated. With PITR you will be able to go to a previous point-in-time.

Or use the [Backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) regularly. Although it transfers the entire db on each backup.

And remember: if you copy an SQLite file or use a regular backup approach while a transaction is active
the copy can be [corrupted](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_backup_or_restore_while_a_transaction_is_active).

Comment: Just a note in case others are trying out undark or SQL-Deleted-Records-Parser, undark's last checkin was 5 years ago, and I tried to use it to recover sqlite DB (created by SQLite 3.11), but it didn't recover any entry.  And I tried SQL-Deleted-Records-Parser, it didn't work neither -- no entry recovered.

Comment: You can try this fork: https://github.com/mlt/undark

Comment: `undark` (both forks) and SQL-Deleted-Records-Parser do not work on the latest SQLite versions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know of a way, either.  However, until you do a VACUUM on the SQLite database file the deleted data is generally not technically removed.  Perhaps you might be able to still recover some of the data using some sort of hex editor on the file.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry -- nope. Backups are the only option I know of.

In the future, consider never issuing DELETE queries, especially from user-accessible forms (let only the DB admin do it, if anyone) -- just include a field in your tables that marks a record as inactive and then factor that in to your queries in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to go in and see the data via a hex-editor. The only info I could find said that metadata was gone so the records weren't going to come back, but the data itself might still be there. It has a lot to do with how important the data is, I suspect it's not important enough for you to dig out a hex editor.

Answer (score 1):

The data isn't always removed from the file straightaway. If there's lots of it and you're desperate, you could use the UNIX command `strings` on the file. This may help you to recover various bits and pieces of human-readable data, but it'll be a hard and inaccurate process.

Answer (score -1):

No way. Without a working backup you won't be able to restore this.

Answer (score -1):

If you accidentally deleted a root folder and its contents:

```
Check the Recycle Bin or Trash for possible recovery.
If you have a recent backup, restore the data from that backup.
Look for an "undo" feature within the application.
Contact the application's support team for assistance.
In critical cases, consider professional data recovery services.
Learn from the incident and implement safeguards to prevent future accidental deletions.
```